# Capturing screenshot in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to take screenshot programatically. So that i write code for it like,

```
CGContextRef context = [self createBitmapContextOfSize:self.frame.size];

//not sure why this is necessary...image renders upside-down and mirrored
CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, self.frame.size.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);

[self.layer renderInContext:context];

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage* background = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);


self.currentScreen = background;
```

Here all code is in custom UIView of UIViewController. Now when i play UIImageView png sequence animation on UIView, then i didn't get updated changes in UIImageView which is subview of custom UIView, why? I got only result is UIImageView with first UIImage.

Basically i need to create an video of my game play like talking tom application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the screenshot of your ImageView with something like this:

```
[[[yourImageView layer] presentationLayer] renderInContext:context];
```

Use NSTimer for calling that getScreenshot function.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Following code is use for the capture the image into the iPhone for that following code to be use.

```
 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-44);
    NSValue *rectObj = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];

    CGRect rectRestored = [rectObj CGRectValue];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(rectRestored.size.width, rectRestored.size.height-44));
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Also store the image into the gallery.

Comment: sorry friend i already follow this code but it not working for me .... it gave me same result. :( upsate

Comment: hello RRB: this code is working into my application for capture the screenshot of a iphone.

Comment: actually i want to create video of game play using capturing screen shots along with sound. I want functionality like talking tom application.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably take a look at AVFoundation and specifically [AVAssetWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as a way of creating videos of your screen content.